# Android - Removing inflated layout xml from a Linear Layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I inflated internetnotconnected.xml to a linear layout. I want to remove View which is inflated layout when user clicks to button. But my way didn't work.

```
if (!EZInternetConnection.isNetworkConnected(context)) {
            LinearLayout LLPureCard = (LinearLayout) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.ll_main_activity_pure_card);
            LinearLayout LLPureCardContent = (LinearLayout) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.ll_main_activity_pure_card_content);
            LLPureCardContent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.internetnotconnected, LLPureCard);
            Button button = (Button) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.b_internet_not_connected_try_connection);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (EZInternetConnection.isNetworkConnected(context)) {

                        LinearLayout LLPureCard = (LinearLayout) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.ll_main_activity_pure_card);
                        LinearLayout LLPureCardContent = (LinearLayout) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.ll_main_activity_pure_card_content);
                        int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier("internetnotconnected", "layout", context.getPackageName());
                        LLPureCard.removeView(((Activity) context).findViewById(id));
                        LLPureCardContent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Get20Words();
                    }
                }
            });
            this.onCancelled();
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would try doing this, replace

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.internetnotconnected, LLPureCard);
```

with

```
final View addedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.internetnotconnected, null);
LLPureCard.addView(addedView);
```

Then in the onClick method replace the line

```
LLPureCard.removeView(((Activity) context).findViewById(id));
```

With

```
LLPureCard.removeView(addedView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier("internetnotconnected", "layout", context.getPackageName());
```

by

```
int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier("internetnotconnected", "id", context.getPackageName());
```

Comment: Can you post full java file? Can you also remove internet checking conditions?